# Should all the headers reported by securityheaders.io be considered as findings?

Tags: tls, http, header

A lot of websites scanned with securityheaders.io are missing different headers.

Should all of these headers be reported as findings or just few of them which are more critical?

Comment: it depends on your audience and what you will be communicating with these findings...

Comment: But I mean from a web application security perspective, should be those headers required? For example in a certified emails provider website or a bank website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Findings are not Vulnerabilities

Should missing security headers be considered a "Finding"? Yes, absolutely. You found a state in the system that is not in accordance to best practice. But what matters is that you put it into proper context. For example, a missing [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) header is definitely a finding, but not necessarily a vulnerability.

### Are those headers required?

"Required by whom?" I would ask back to you. If the security requirements the company itself writes dictate that all web-applications must contain all security headers that are considered best practice, then they are definitely required.

I'm not in the position to comment whether or not there is a legal requirement to have them, although I personally have never heard such a thing.

### How should I proceed when I see missing security headers?

I report them as an informational finding. They're a missing security feature, and they should be implemented if it is possible. I would put a bit more emphasis on them if there were related attacks (e.g. XSS and a missing CSP), and would explain how the presence of this header would have made the attack more difficult or even prevented it, but it should still be treated as a low-severity finding.

Answer (score 0):

When you run an automated scanner, the results alone will rarely detect a security issue definitively. It is up to the user to evaluate the scanner's results, and determine the validity (e.g. not false positive) and whether there is any significance.

Depending on the particular engagement, it may vary what is considered as a "finding". However, unless you can actually demonstrate a significant negative security impact from the missing/misconfigured header, I would say they are not worth reporting. If part of a larger report, they possibly may be mentioned as an informational finding, but they aren't worth much alone.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: it depends on the risk posed to the organization based on the business usage performed by the application. You can let them know the finding exists, but let them know there may be bigger fish to fry.